# Cast Linq IEnumerable to Class that inherits Ienumerable

Tags: linq, ienumerable, casting

I have a resultset class:

```
Public Class AResultSet
    Implements IEnumerable(Of ConcreteResult)

    Private _list As List(Of ConcreteResult)

    Public Sub New()
        _list = New List(Of ConcreteResult)
    End Sub

    Public Function GetEnumerator() As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator(Of ConcreteResult) Implements System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of ConcreteResult).GetEnumerator
        Return _list.GetEnumerator
    End Function

    Public Function GetEnumerator1() As System.Collections.IEnumerator Implements System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator
        Return _list.GetEnumerator
    End Function
End Class
```

and a linq query:

```
Dim res As AResultSet = (From pk In testPackages, _
         pp In pk.PackagePriceCollection _
          Select New ConcreteResult(pk, pp))
```

But I get a cast error. So if I change the

```
Dim res As AResultSet
```

To:

```
Dim res As IEnumerable(Of ConcreteResult)
```

It works. But I want to cast the linq query result to the type AResultSet, which is also  an IEnumerable(Of ConrecteResult).

Or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

The result of calling `Select` *is not* an `AResultSet`, which is why the cast will fail. Nothing in the query knows that you want to create a `AResultSet`. Just because the result and `AResultSet` both implement the same interface doesn't mean they're the same type.

You could *create* an instance of `AResultSet` from the results, however:

```
Dim query = (From pk In testPackages, _
     pp In pk.PackagePriceCollection _
     Select New ConcreteResult(pk, pp))
Dim res as AResultSet = new AResultSet(query.ToList)
```

Answer (score 0):

While it's unclear to me why you might want to create a class to duplicate the functionality of `List(Of T)`, what you are trying to do is not directly possible. You should either create an implicit (`Widening`) user defined cast operator in your class or create a constructor that takes an `IEnumerable(Of ConcreteResult)` and uses that to fill the private list field.

```
Public Class AResultSet
      Implements IEnumerable(Of ConcreteResult)
   Private list As List(Of ConcreteResult)
   Private Sub New(l As List(Of ConcreteResult))
      list = l
   End Sub
   Public Shared Widening Operator CType(seq As IEnumerable(Of ConcreteResult)) As AResultSet
      Return New AResultset(seq.ToList())
   End Sub
   ...
End Class
```